# Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr set function not working on 1.6.1

Tags: c++, json, poco-libraries

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
Poco::JSON::Parser a;
Poco::Dynamic::Var v = a.parse(str); //str is a json string
Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr p = v.extract<Poco::JSON::Object::Ptr>();
p->set("key","value");
```

in Poco v 1.6.0 this works completely fine, and the content of v is changed according to the set function, yet in 1.6.1 it's not working anymore, is there a difference on the set function call between 1.6.0 and 1.6.1? Or what could be the potential problem? (My current observation is that in 1.6.1 the set line is not executed at all.)

Thank you for reading this.

Note: If there's any work around that can achieve the same effect but doesn't have to use the set function I'll be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I find out the answer today and decided to share with people.

Answer: the set() function Poco::JSON::Object is different in 1.6.0 and 1.6.1. In 1.6.1 it will not function if there's already value assigned to that give key, while in 1.6.0 it will just overwrite it. A very simple work around for 1.6.1 is you can first do remove() function then do the set() function, then it will work the same. But yes, the implementation is different and can be checked in the source code of the Poco library.